# Ubunto Core 22.04 Raspberry pi - linux-modules-extra-raspi

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core, microk8s

I have Ubuntu Core on a raspberry pi 4 and installed microk8s via snap.
I see regular errors in calico:
"panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

A bit of googling leads me to believe that I need to install:
"linux-modules-extra-raspi"
in order to resolve the error.

Of course, no snap exists for that package and I can't use apt.

How do you resolve this type of issue where you want/need a specific package when running core?

Comment: A "nil pointer dereference" is typically a straighforward bug, not usually a clue of missing software. Please file a bug report with the application developers.

Comment: Thanks, was basing this off:
https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/2680
Without reinstalling on server and installing it, I can't verify if that would actually fix it.
Ultimately, lloks like maybe this (still open) issue:
https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/5410